# How to configure makecall using GnuGK or OpenH323gk?

Tags: c++, c, bug-tracking, voip

When i use GnuGK/Openh323gk from its telnet session how can i do makecall?

```
$ telnet localhost 7000
;
makecall alias1 alias2

$ ./gnugk -c config.ini -ttt
2011/05/23 11:10:48.957 1       MakeCall.cxx(55)    MakeCallEndpoint: Error registering with gatekeeper at "<my public ip>"
2011/05/23 11:10:49.458 1        SoftPBX.cxx(483)   GK  SoftPBX: MakeCall registration of pseudo-endpoint failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GnuGk uses an internal endpoint to initiate calls. This endpoint is treated exactly like any other external endpoint and needs to register with GnuGk.

Your quoted trace lines indicate that this registration fails. Make sure it is not blocked by any authorization rule and that it is using an alias that isn't already used by something else:

```
[CTI::MakeCall]
Endpoint=<free alias name>
```

In a level 3 trace you should be able to see the registration of this internal endpoint and the confirm or reject message from GnuGk.

Comment: I have this now, but still i have same error [CTI::MakeCall] EndpointAlias=InternalMakeCallEP Gatekeeper=<public ip> Interface=<public ip>:1730